# mySQL :: insert into table, data from another table?

Tags: sql, mysql

I was wondering if there is a way to do this purely in sql:

```
q1 = SELECT campaign_id, from_number, received_msg, date_received 
     FROM `received_txts` WHERE `campaign_id` = '8';
INSERT INTO action_2_members (campaign_id, mobile, vote, vote_date)    
    VALUES(q1.campaign_id, q1.from_number, q1.received_msg, q1.date_received);
```

**Note:** q1 would return about 30k rows.

Is there any way to do what I am attempting above in straight sql?
To just pull the data straight from one table (basically a raw data table) and insert into another table (basically a processed data table)?

Answer (score 447, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO action_2_members (campaign_id, mobile, vote, vote_date)  
SELECT campaign_id, from_number, received_msg, date_received
  FROM `received_txts`
 WHERE `campaign_id` = '8'
```

Comment: @InSane: 1) give an answer 2) correct the question formatting. Don't miss the order next time ;-)

Comment: ha ha :-) yup..i have never managed to get my priorities sorted! :-D

Comment: Working! +1 Perfect and very fast! Thanks mate. Just had to remove brackets from SELECT fields...

Comment: @zerkms; Will triggers work with this `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` statement?

Comment: @haccks I believe the same as if it was just a "normal" `INSERT`

Comment: @zerkms; Yes, you are right. Actually I just wrote a trigger and tested it now and it worked as it was with normal `INSERT`. Thanks. But, still not sure whether doing this is correct or not.

Comment: it's worked like a charm and I also learn how to do insertion from a table to another table automatically using windows Task Scheduler and Batch file. Learn more: https://ddroid509ht.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 40):

for whole row

```
insert into xyz select * from xyz2 where id="1";
```

for selected column

```
insert into xyz(t_id,v_id,f_name) select t_id,v_id,f_name from xyz2 where id="1";
```

Comment: The whole row approach fails if there's already an existing record with a matching primary key.

Comment: Did you find any solution? 
<The whole row approach fails if there's already an existing record with a matching primary key.>

Answer (score 17):

Answered by [zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251311/zerkms) is the correct method. But, if someone looking to insert more extra column in the table then you can get it from the following:

```
INSERT INTO action_2_members (`campaign_id`, `mobile`, `email`, `vote`, `vote_date`, `current_time`)
SELECT `campaign_id`, `from_number`, 'example@domain.xyz', `received_msg`, `date_received`, 1502309889 FROM `received_txts` WHERE `campaign_id` = '8'
```

In the above query, there are 2 extra columns named **email** & **current_time**.

Comment: What if I wanted to insert three rows of data with the same values from the select but different values for the 'additional' columns added such as email and current_time?

Answer (score 7):

```
INSERT INTO Table1 SELECT * FROM Table2
```

Comment: This is a very low quality answer. Plus, unlike the accepted answer, it doesn't even try to relate to information included in the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO preliminary_image (style_id,pre_image_status,file_extension,reviewer_id,
uploader_id,is_deleted,last_updated) 

SELECT '4827499',pre_image_status,file_extension,reviewer_id,
uploader_id,'0',last_updated FROM preliminary_image WHERE style_id=4827488
```

***Analysis***

We can use above query if we want to copy data from one table to another table in mysql

1. Here source and destination table are same, we can use different tables also.
2. Few columns we are not copying like **style_id** and **is_deleted** so we selected them hard coded from another table
3. Table we used in source also contains auto increment field so we left that column and it get inserted automatically with execution of query.

***Execution results***

1 queries executed, 1 success, 0 errors, 0 warnings

Query: insert into preliminary_image (style_id,pre_image_status,file_extension,reviewer_id,uploader_id,is_deleted,last_updated) select ...

5 row(s) affected

Execution Time : 0.385 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0.386 sec

Answer (score 0):

This query is for add data from one table to another table
using  foreign key

```
let qry = "INSERT INTO `tb_customer_master` (`My_Referral_Code`, `City_Id`, `Cust_Name`, `Reg_Date_Time`, `Mobile_Number`, `Email_Id`, `Gender`, `Cust_Age`, `Profile_Image`, `Token`, `App_Type`, `Refer_By_Referral_Code`, `Status`) values ('" + randomstring.generate(7) + "', '" + req.body.City_Id + "', '" + req.body.Cust_Name + "', '" + req.body.Reg_Date_Time + "','" + req.body.Mobile_Number + "','" + req.body.Email_Id + "','" + req.body.Gender + "','" + req.body.Cust_Age + "','" + req.body.Profile_Image + "','" + req.body.Token + "','" + req.body.App_Type + "','" + req.body.Refer_By_Referral_Code + "','" + req.body.Status + "')";
                        connection.query(qry, (err, rows) => {
                            if (err) { res.send(err) } else {
                                let insert = "INSERT INTO `tb_customer_and_transaction_master` (`Cust_Id`)values ('" + rows.insertId + "')";
                                connection.query(insert, (err) => {
                                    if (err) {
                                        res.json(err)
                                    } else {
                                        res.json("Customer added")
                                    }
                                })
                            }
    
    
                        })
                    }
                }
    
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$insertdata="insert into partner_products(partner_id,partner_category_id,main_category_id, inventory_id,partner_product_name, partner_product_brand, partner_product_price,partner_product_quantity,partner_product_unit) select '123',partner_category_id,main_category_id,inventory_id, item_name,brand_name,item_price,item_qty, item_unit from inventory where partner_category_id='1'";
```

Comment: Please explain your solution. Answers which do not have an explanation and are only code get flagged as low effort.

Comment: Please provide an explanation for your answer without just the code. It will help someone to learn from your answer, not to just copy it