# Update table with info from another table with modifications

Tags: mysql

I want to move data (with modifications) from one table to another.

```
UPDATE table2 
SET val_new=(SELECT (table1.val_old - SUM(table3.val_2)) as some1 
FROM table3 
INNER JOIN table1 ON table3.id_some=.table1.id_some 
WHERE table3.id_typ<=2 
AND table3.id_status=1 
group by table3.id_some);
```

I have error:

```
Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

What I must do to correct this query?

Comment: Don't you need an INSERT rather than an UPDATE?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241621/mysql-insert-into-table-data-from-another-table) should help.

Comment: No, because I have data in table2 and I must change only column val_new.

Comment: You want to set the `val_new` column to the same thing in every row of `table2`?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to fix is this:

```
UPDATE table2 SET 
val_new=ifnull((
     SELECT (table1.val_old - SUM(table3.val_2)) as some1 
     FROM table3 
     INNER JOIN table1 ON table3.id_some=.table1.id_some 
     WHERE table3.id_typ<=2 
     AND table3.id_status=1 
     WHERE table3.table2_id = table2.id -- ADDED THIS LINE
     group by table3.id_some), val_new);
```

Comment: I added:  
`AND table3.table2_id = table2.id`  
and works almost perfect. Now I have warning:  
`76 row(s) affected, 49 warning(s): 1048 Column 'val_new' cannot be null 1048 Column 'val_new' cannot be null 1048 Column 'val_new' cannot be null 1048 Column 'val_new' (...) `

Comment: I've edited the SQL to not update if the value from the sub query returns a null. Try it now