# How can I fill my table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to fill up TableE, and I have these tables.

TableA

```
+------+--------+--------+
| A_ID | A_NAME | A_TYPE |
+------+--------+--------+
|   1  |  apple |    1   |
+------+--------+--------+
```

TableB

```
+------+---------+--------+
| B_ID | B_NAME  | FROM_A |
+------+---------+--------+
|   1  | A_NAME  | A_ID   |
+------+---------+--------+
```

TableC

```
+-------+------------+
|  C_ID |   C_NAME   |
+-------+------------+
| A_TYPE|    fruit   |
+-------+------------+
| A_TYPE| vegetables |
+-------+------------+
```

TableD

```
+------+---------+
| D_ID | D_NAME  |
+------+---------+
|   1  |  fruit  |
+------+---------+
```

TableE

```
+------+--------+
| E_ID | E_NAME |
+------+--------+
| B_ID |  D_ID  |
+------+--------+
```

How can I fill `TableE` with `TableB B_ID` and `TableD D_ID`, where the `C_Name =` with D_Name, and between `TableC` and `TableD` no key, only through `TableA` and `TableB`, where the `A_ID` is the key.

So, if apple is a fruit, write in `TableE` the `B_ID` and `D_ID`, with one SQL statement.
How can I do this?

I have 2000 row in TableA and TableB
I want to compare the C_Name with D_Name, and if its the same, write in the TableE the ID from TableB and the ID from TableD.

Comment: possible duplicate :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241621/mysql-insert-into-table-data-from-another-table

Comment: Could you please write in English what exactly should happen (with numbers, please. Step by step).

Comment: I have 2000 row in TableA and TableB I want to compare the C_Name with D_Name, and if its the same, write in the TableE the ID from TableB and the ID from TableD.

Comment: You want to add B and D to E but where do A come in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  INSERT INTO TableE (E_ID , E_NAME)
  SELECT b.B_ID ,d.D_ID FROM TableA a 
  INNER JOIN TableB b ON b.FROM_A = a.A_ID
  INNER JOIN TableC c ON c.C_ID  = a.A_TYPE
  INNER JOIN TableD d ON  d.D_NAME = c.C_NAME
```

Comment: Error in the 6. line
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET E_ID = b.B_ID , E_NAME = d.D_ID' at line 6

Comment: @MiszterSoul check now myedited answer