# ODBC/MYSQL Insert a Query Result from ODBC to a databse in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, odbc

I'm connecting to a cloud database through an ODBC connection:

```
$conn = odbc_connect('MYDATABASE','','');
if (!$conn) {
    exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);
}

$sql = "SELECT DATETIME_ID, NAME, Sum(CNDROP) AS DATA
        FROM   MY_TABLE
        WHERE DATETIME_ID>='2014-09-28:00:00:00'
          and DATETIME_ID<='2014-09-28 23:00:00'
          and NAME IN ('CC2')
        GROUP BY DATETIME_ID, NAME ORDER BY DATETIME_ID, NAME";

$rs = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
if (!$rs) {
    exit("Consulta fallida");
}

$result = odbc_exec($conn,$sql) or die(exit("Error en odbc_exec"));
print odbc_result_all($result,"border=1");

odbc_close($conn);
```

I can get the data, and print the data, but now I need insert that data into a MySQL database into my computer.

I don't have any idea how to do it, so I need help with an example. I tried to search on google but nothing was helpful.

Comment: Did you Google your question or looked at the manual? http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-exec.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, i did. But i don't see any information to migrate a query into a table in a mysql database.

Comment: So Luis, the real question is, you want to use your query's results and then insert it based on that, correct?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, i want insert the query result in a another database (localhost mysql database),

Comment: See this Q&A on Stack http://stackoverflow.com/q/4241621/ and Google "insert in other table from query mysql" if you wish to further your research.

Comment: @Fred-ii-Thanks Fred, but i already saw some of those comments/threads. My doubt is, in those examples/case, the tables are in the same "database" or in the same connection. I have 2 "connection", one in ODBC (the database from i get the data) and the other in mysql (the database where I wanna send the data). And if i do like "INSERT INTO THEOTHERTABLE (DATETIME_ID, NAME, CNDROP)", it gives me a error that it can't found THEOTHERTABLE in the database.

Comment: You're welcome Luis. I won't be able to help any further, sorry; those are types of queries I don't do. I will upvote the question though, and hope someone else will pick up on it. *Cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii-Thanks Fred, if i find the question i'll post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1:

**Function to SELECT**

```
function get_data_from_cloud(){
    $conn=odbc_connect('CLOUD','','');
    if (!$conn) {
        exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);
    }
    $sql="SELECT DATETIME, NAME, CNDROP 
          FROM TABLE1 
          WHERE DATETIME>='2014-09-28 00:00:00' and 
                DATETIME<='2014-09-28 23:00:00' and 
                NAME IN ('PETER') 
          GROUP BY DATETIME, NAME 
          ORDER BY DATETIME, NAME";

    $result=odbc_exec($conn,$sql)or die(exit("Error en odbc_exec"));

    $data = array();
    while (odbc_fetch_row($result)) {
        $data[]=array('DATETIME' => odbc_result ($result, "DATETIME"), 
                      'NAME'=> odbc_result ($result, "NAME"), 
                      'CNDROP'=> odbc_result ($result, "CNDROP"));
    }
    return $data;   
}
```

**Function to INSERT**

```
function insert_cloud_data($cloud_data=array()){
    $conn=odbc_connect('LOCAL','','');
    if (!$conn) {
        exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);
    }
    foreach($cloud_data as $data){
        $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO Prueba (DATIME, NAME, CNDROP)
                       VALUES ( '%s','%s','%s')",
                      $data['DATETIME'], $data['NAME'], $data['CNDROP']);
        $rs = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);    

        if (!$rs) {
            error_log("Consulta fallida");
        }   
    }

    odbc_close($conn);
}
```

---

### Option 2:

**Function to SELECT**

```
function get_data_from_cloud(){
    $conn=odbc_connect('CLOUD','','');
    if (!$conn) {
        exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);
    }
    $sql="SELECT DATETIME, NAME, CNDROP 
          FROM TABLE1 
          WHERE DATETIME>='2014-09-28 00:00:00' and 
                DATETIME<='2014-09-28 23:00:00' and 
                NAME IN ('PETER') 
          GROUP BY DATETIME, NAME 
          ORDER BY DATETIME, NAME";

    $result=odbc_exec($conn,$sql)or die(exit("Error en odbc_exec"));

    $data = array();
    while (odbc_fetch_row($result)) {
        $data[]=array(odbc_result ($result, "DATETIME"),
                      odbc_result ($result, "NAME"),
                      odbc_result ($result, "CNDROP"));
    }
    return $data;   
}
```

**Function to INSERT**

```
function insert_cloud_data($cloud_data=array()){
    $conn=odbc_connect('LOCAL','','');
    if (!$conn) {
        exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO Prueba (DATIME, NAME, CNDROP)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = odbc_prepare($conn, $sql);
    if(!$stmt) die("could not prepare statement ".$sql);

    foreach($cloud_data as $data){
        odbc_execute($stmt, $data);  
    }

    odbc_close($conn);
}
```

**USAGE**

```
$cloud_data = get_data_from_cloud();
insert_cloud_data($cloud_data);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'm understanding the logic now, but i get those error "Undefined variable: Query_ID" and "odbc_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given" Thanks a lot.

Comment: love you man, Thanks a lot, it seem to be working now, by the way is "sprintf" not "sprint" :). Can i ask you another last thing?

Comment: i'll vote for sure when i get more reputation. Ok, my last doubt is the DATETIME is in timestamp format wich reflect something like 2014-09-04 00:00:00, i'm ussing Microsoft Access and i need change that to format "Date" string cause it give me a error (Data type mismatch in criteria expression.), but i wanna show in that new "date string" the date exactly how timestamp "2014-09-04 00:00:00", I do not know if i explained well. Thanks meda.

Comment: @LuisSira `INSERT INTO Prueba (DATIME, NAME, CNDROP) VALUES ( #%s#,'%s','%s'`

Comment: Syntax error in date in query expression '#2014-09-28 00:00:00.000000'

Comment: @LuisSira where exactly are you getting this error, in access or while inserting

Comment: on line 45 wich is in function insert_cloud_data. this is the line 45   $rs = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);

Comment: no @LuisSira `Data type mismatch in criteria expression.` that one

Comment: Oh, while inserting, cause i access and get a timestamp value, and my column in Microsfot Access isn't in a timestamp format, i can put it in "string" or "date" format, so is while i'm inserting the data, cause exist a mismatch.

Comment: @LuisSira do you still need help, did you figure this out. let me know

Comment: i change it to a mysql database through ODBC, and mysql support timestamp format, but maybe i should have to change the format later, not sure, but if i get in trouble i can ask you again? Thanks by the way, helped me so much.

Comment: Hello meda, you know about jquery $_POST/$_GET?

Comment: Yes I saw you asked a question but did not say what didnt work

Comment: i asked a new question where i explain it better, i can send now the var to one page to another page without refreshing, i need is get the result data and load it in a javascript var in the first page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is different approach.

Create $conn1 (cloud) and $conn2 (localhost).  Query the $conn1 then use php while and insert command into $conn2.

```
$conn1 = (cloud);
$conn2 = (localhost);

$query = "SELECT ...";
$result = odbc_exec($conn1,$query);
while( fetch result data ) {
   $query = "INSERT ....";
   odbc_exec($conn2,$query);
}
```

Comment: @Luis Sira For your [INSERT](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp) statement you need to add the VALUES behind by using [ODBC_RESULT](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-result.php).