# Add another table with php/mysqli

Tags: php, database, select, mysqli

I have to insert data from another table,but same database. Can someone help me how to achieve that?

Here is my working code for one table:

Code is taken from http://www.angularcode.com/demo-of-a-simple-crud-restful-php-service-used-with-angularjs-and-mysql/

```
private function xyz(){ 
    if($this->get_request_method() != "GET"){
            $this->response('',406);
    }
    $id = (int)$this->_request['id'];
    if($id > 0){    
        $query="SELECT distinct t.field1, t.field2, t.field3 FROM table1 t where t.field1=$id";
        $r = $this->mysqli->query($query) or die($this->mysqli->error.__LINE__);
        if($r->num_rows > 0) {
            $result = $r->fetch_assoc();    
            $this->response($this->json($result), 200);
        }
    }
    $this->response('',204);
}
```

Comment: What part of that is angular?

Comment: none, corrected it. no angularjs in this code, ofc.

Comment: Where is the part what you have tried to insert data from one table into another?

Comment: you can insert data from one table to another using only mysql. no php is needed.

Comment: Sorry, can you give me an example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241621/mysql-insert-into-table-data-from-another-table

Comment: You can do from as many tables as needed. INSERT INTO table SET val1 = (SELECT val1 FROM table1), val2=(SELECT val2 FROM table2) etc

Comment: I'll try that out, thanks. But is there any way possible to implement another table in my given code?