# Moving columns between two tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working on PHP Codeigniter with MySQL database, I have two tables Student (Original table) and Student1 (temporary table) and both tables have different columns.

I am uploading bulk of student list from a CSV file into that Student1 (temporary table), later I have to move those student details into Student (Original table). How can I do this?

This is different case, I am not only asking about executing the query, instead I have to do it using MVC (CodeIgniter).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql :: insert into table, data from another table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241621/mysql-insert-into-table-data-from-another-table)

Answer (score 0):

With this query:

```
INSERT INTO Student(first, last, dob) SELECT first, last, dob FROM Student1
```

Change column names to the appropriate column names of each table.

Answer (score 0):

use this sql which help you

```
INSERT INTO Student(field1,field2,field3)
SELECT field1,field2,field2
FROM Student1;
```

you can use this code for ci

```
$query = $this->db->query('INSERT Student (field1, field2, field3)
                           SELECT field1, field2, field3
                           FROM Student');
```

this is format

INSERT INTO database2.table1 (field1,field2,field3)
SELECT table2.field1,table2.field2,table2.field3
FROM table2;

for more information

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

Answer (score 0):

For example
**Student** has *id* and *name*; 
**Student1** has *id*, *firstname*, *lastname*

You could fill **Student** by request:

`INSERT INTO Student SELECT id, CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) FROM Student1;`

If **Student** is not empty, you could append records (change *id* to *null*,
I assume that *id* column is autoincrement):

`INSERT INTO Student SELECT null, CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) FROM Student1;`