# Copy data from a table to another without ID

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a MySQL statement to copy data from one table to another.

```
$sql2 = "INSERT one SELECT id, user_id, name FROM two WHERE user_id='1'";
```

Both tables are using the same columns: `id`, `user_id` and `name`.

I want to copy the data from table `two` to table `one`. When I execute the script I can see that all the data in table `two` is copied to table `one`. Also the column `id`.

I want to keep the `id` in table `one` as a unique value. I dont want to copy the `id` from table `two` to `one`. I just want to copy the columns `user_id` and `name` and want to auto increment the `id` in table `one`.

When I execute the script without `id` I get a error that says that the colums in `one` and `two` are not the same.

Does someone know how I can solve this problem and copy the data without the `id` column

Comment: 'If you do not specify a list of column names for INSERT ... VALUES or INSERT ... SELECT, values for every column in the table must be provided by the VALUES list or the SELECT statement.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html

Comment: `insert into one (user_id, name) select user_id, name from two where ...` like so?

Comment: `user_id='1'`  also general MySQL rule if the columns datatype is INT query it as a INT and not a string.  If you query it as a string MySQL's autocasting can mess things up and the optimizer might be unable to use indexes if anny.

Comment: And it only works if the id is an auto_increment value, which is stated by the OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this syntax for your query:

```
INSERT INTO `one` (`user_id`, `name`) SELECT `user_id`, `name` FROM `two` WHERE `user_id` = 1
```

---

The rows that match the `WHERE` clause in the `SELECT` statement will be copied to table `one`.

As the `id` field is omitted both in the `SELECT` and `INSERT` statements then rows created into `one` will get `id` as per auto-increment value.

---

I assumed `user_id` is a numeric column (of type `int`, `bigint`...) so I removed the single quotes around the value `1`.

Quotes should be used if the field contains a string (ex. column of type `char`, `varchar`...)

Comment: `user_id='1'` also general MySQL rule if the columns datatype is INT query it as a INT and not a string. If you query it as a string MySQL's autocasting can mess things up and the optimizer might be unable to use indexes if anny.

Comment: I doubt that this actually works. Didn't try it, though. The brackets around the select statement seem a little bit odd to me

Comment: @RaymondNijland you're right. But the OP query puts `1` between single quotes. We don't know `user_id` column type from the information provided by the OP.

Comment: "We don't know user_id column type from the information provided by the OP" that's why i said " **if** the columns datatype is INT query it as a INT and not a string"

Comment: @Psi the round brackets around the select statement are optional but I found they make the query more readable. It works: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4241646/1579327

Comment: @Paolo I believe you, the syntax just came as a surprise to me, never used it that way