# Insert an specific row from a table in a database A to another table in a database B

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I want to copy a row for example whith `ID=23` in a table A into another table with `ID=30` into another database. I got this

```
INSERT INTO pacaya_control_venta.tb_venta_pacaya WHERE ID=33
SELECT * FROM llamadas.tb_venta_pacaya WHERE ID = 48;
```

But I think the double `WHERE` is wrong. Any thoughts???

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add some example data and the database schema. Also, please add the error message you get. Also, please tell us why you talk about `ID=23` and `ID=30` but your SQL shows `ID=33` and `ID=48`.

Comment: Your inital SQL (before your edit) was syntatically wrong.  The "double where" is also incorrect.  See this duplicate for the correct syntax: [mysql :: insert into table, data from another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241621/mysql-insert-into-table-data-from-another-table).  If you need to alter the contents of the row you're inserting, use a [values](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) clause.

Comment: @paulsm4 Maybe it's not a duplicate, because I think they want to change the value of the `ID` column, but they have to [edit] their question to answer that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming both the table contain the same columns (col1, col2, ...)   and the db are on the same server 
 for copy a row you should use update  ..  not insert

```
UPDATE pacaya_control_venta.tb_venta_pacaya  a
INNER JOIN llamadas.tb_venta_pacaya  b ON a.id=33 and b.id = 48 
SET a.col1 = b.col1,
    a.col2 = b.col2, 
    .....
```

insert is for create a new row  not for updated existing one

```
INSERT INTO pacaya_control_venta.tb_venta_pacaya 
SELECT * 
FROM llamadas.tb_venta_pacaya 
WHERE ID = 48;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
INSERT INTO pacaya_control_venta.tb_venta_pacaya (id, col1,col2,col3,col4,...)
  SELECT 33, col2, col3, col4,.... FROM llamadas.tb_venta_pacaya WHERE ID = 48;
```